# How to More Elegantly Calculate Epoch Time for Next Sunday at Midnight in Dart?

Tags: dart, time

When a user opens my app, there's a countdown timer that shows how much time left until Sunday at midnight (which is when the week's contest would end).

To get the initial value used in the countdown, my code adds 604800000 (which is the amount of milliseconds in a week) in a loop to a starting value of 1595203200000 (which the milliseconds since epoch of an arbitrary past Sunday at midnight) until it's greater than now:

```
int now = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
int nextSundayAtMidnight = 1595203200000; // starting value is from arbitrary past Sunday at midnight

while (now > nextSundayAtMidnight) {
  print('now is still greater than nextSundayAtMidnight so adding another 604800000 until it\'s not');
  nextSundayAtMidnight += 604800000;
}

print('nextSundayAtMidnight is $nextSundayAtMidnight');
```

It works, but it seems like there should be a better way that's based on DateTime.now without having to manually specify that arbitrary starting value. Is there?

What's the syntax in dart to do this more elegantly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code uses addition of the difference in weekdays to get the date of the upcoming Sunday and then shifts the exact `DateTime` to being at 11:59:59 pm. There are comments in the code that describe what each line does.

It uses the many helpful methods already provided in the [`DateTime` class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) in dart.

```dart
void main()
{
  var now = DateTime.now();

  //Obtains a time on the date of next sunday
  var nextSunday = now.add(Duration(days: DateTime.sunday - now.weekday));

  //Shifts the time to being 11:59:59 pm on that sunday
  var nextSundayMidnight = DateTime(nextSunday.year, nextSunday.month, nextSunday.day + 1).subtract(Duration(seconds: 1));
  
  //Gets the difference in the time of sunday at midnight and now
  var timeToSundayMidnight = nextSundayMidnight.difference(now);
  
  print(timeToSundayMidnight);
}
```